# Process startup after boot

Tags: process

I know the following are ways processes get started in Linux

- from init.d (or similar)
- from shell (by user)
- forked by a running native daemon

Is it ever possible on Linux for a process to be started, and it does not fall in the above categories?  For example, could a process be started without knowledge of the user?

Comment: Processes can be started by *at, cron, batch* commands, which might fall into the fuzzy category "...without knowledge of user..."

Comment: For ar, cron, batch etc. what would they exactly run .. launch a new shell, fork, then execve ?

Comment: *apt-get source cron* (and likewise for at) will satisfy your curiosity. Also, not all crons are alike, I am on vixie-cron, do not know about you. In vixie-cron there is a comment (I will spare you the actual code) that says: *if there are no debug flags turned on, fork as a daemon should.*

Comment: How, exactly, are you defining "knowledge of the user"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Linux, almost **all processes** (including servers and daemon programs) **are started with a [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)** (sometimes implemented in your standard C library using [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html)) **often followed by [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)** syscall. The [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) library function use these (and some few others) [syscalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html)....)

The only **exceptions are a *few* processes magically started by the kernel**. These include:

- **[init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init)** (generally `/sbin/init`, which could be [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) these days, but you can boot your kernel and pass `init=/bin/bash` to it thru GRUB) which is started at kernel initialization.
- some *very few programs started magically by the kernel* (when some external event occurs), e.g. sometimes [modprobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modprobe), [hotplug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_swapping), etc....

<sup>`init` existed in 1980 era Unixes (e.g. SunOS3). AFAIK, automagically started `hotplug`-like processes are a recent Linux addition (probably Linux 3, or at least 2.6, see also [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev))</sup>

Most programs and processes (including `login`, `bash`, `getty`, `cron`, `atd`, `mysqld`) are all descendants of `init`  with `fork` & `execve`
You basically can ignore the exceptions (like `hotplug`), and you could have a Linux system where every process is descendant of `init` (that was the case with Linux 1.x kernels in the previous century). Use [pstree(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pstree.1.html) to see the tree of processes.

Read wikipage about [Linux startup process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process) & [From PowerUp to Bash Prompt](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/From-PowerUp-To-Bash-Prompt-HOWTO.html) (which might be slightly outdated, but most of it is still true).

[setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) is a clever mechanism related to privileges (see also [setreuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html), [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), [namespaces(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html)).

I recommend reading [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) at first. Some few features or syscalls appeared after that book (e.g. [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html), [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html), [epoll(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) ....).

Comment: so for processes running with my user's privilege on my machine .. they did fork, execve, then setuid ?

Comment: Yes, ... but setuid executables have their setuid bit set, and it is `/sbin/login` which is *setuid*, not most programs.

Comment: No I meant to drop privileges ..